# Left Outer Join Entity Framework Core 1.1.0

Tags: entity-framework, linq, left-join

I am trying to implement a left join with EF Core 1.1.0. I know there were problems with earlier versions, but I thought this was fixed now. Besides, the same problem appears with EF6 so I think it's something I am doing wrong.

My table contains positions in an organization with a reference to their superior. I have the following entity model:

```
public class Position
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public int SuperiorID { get; set; }
}
```

`SuperiorID` points to another record in the same table, or zero if not applicable.

I have the following view model:

```
public class PositionListViewModel
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public string Superior { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the following query in LINQPad, the results are exactly as expected:

```
from pos in Positions
join sup in Positions on pos.SuperiorID equals sup.ID into temp
from sup in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {pos, sup.JobTitle}
```

But when I try this query in my application:

```
var result =
    from pos in _context.Positions
    join sup in _context.Positions on pos.SuperiorID equals sup.ID into temp
    from sup in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new PositionListViewModel() { Position = pos, Superior = sup.JobTitle };
```

`result` is null and an error is returned `.get_Items requires calling method System.RuntimeType.IsEnumDefined, which cannot be called in this context. Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057`. I have not been able to find anything on this error. The same error results if I try to return an anonymous type.

I can get around it by adding an extra field `SupTitle` to the entity model and using `.fromSql`, but this feels awkward and I think would become quite nasty if I later wanted to add additional joins to the query.

```
var result = _context.Positions.FromSql(
    "SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[SuperiorID], [t1].[Title] AS [SupTitle] " +
    "FROM [Positions] AS [t0] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Positions] AS [t1] " +
    "ON [t0].[SuperiorID] = [t1].[ID]");
```

If I make it an inner join by removing the `into` clause and the `DefaultIfEmpty()` line, it works but obviously I don't get rows where `SuperiorID == 0`.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, can I run two queries and merge the results before sending them to the view? That way, I could run the inner join and then append a simple `where SuperiorID == 0` query.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a couple of days, I found a solution about ten minutes after posting the question.

I changed the entity model to this:

```
public class Position
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Position Superior { get; set; }
}
```

And then the following query works just as I had hoped:

```
var result =
    from pos in _context.Positions
    select new PositionListViewModel()
    {
        Position = pos,
        Superior = pos.Superior == null ? "None" : pos.Superior.Title
    };
```